No internet connection on Hyper-V virtual machine in VPS
I am running a Windows 10 virtual machine (Hyper-V) on Windows Server 2022 (VPS). I need my virtual machine to be on the same LAN as my Windows Server. To do this, I have configured a virtual switch as follows:
https://i.sstatic.net/8Mns2WMT.png
After that I specified this switch in the virtual machine settings:
https://i.sstatic.net/2wEaAwM6.png
However, there is still no internet connection in the virtual machine itself:
https://i.sstatic.net/E4H7CaMZ.png
Please help me to solve this problem. If you need additional details for clarification - ask me and I will attach everything needed.

Where's the ipconfig and route table information?

It looks like you're using nested virtualization. If that's the case then you probably need to enable MAC address spoofing on the vNIC of the VM.


It is relevant only if you are nesting inside and further bridging a VM to the Hyper-V VM (in which case the Hyper-V switch will be receiving frames with different source MACs). (Strictly speaking it has nothing to do with nested virtualization at all.) Yet the indication you are talking about is that the Hyper-V hypervisor is nesting inside a KVM.

Unfortunately, nothing has changed.
